# Node.jsでアップデートエラー: Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v6.17.1. Update it

Tags: aws, node.js

MacOsMojave
10.14.6

AWSでデプロイしようとすると、

```
Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v6.17.1. Update it.
```

というエラーが発生します
Node.jsをアップデートしなさいというエラーみたいですが
私のバージョンは

```
node -v
v15.2.1
```

でありv6.17.1ではありません

それはひとまず置いといて[こちら](https://qiita.com/m-dove/items/a60b1a09d32299d215bb)で対処しようとしましたが
最初の削除の時点で

```
sudo: yum: command not found
```

が出てしまい問題解決できず前に進めません

検索しても解決方法は上記の方法のようなばかりで困っています

ご教授お願いします

### 追記

carriawave.rb

```
require 'carrierwave/storage/abstract'
require 'carrierwave/storage/file'
require 'carrierwave/storage/fog'

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test? 
  elsif Rails.env.production?
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: 'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    region: 'ap-northeast-1'
  }

  config.fog_directory  = 'rails-baseball-app'
  config.asset_host = 'https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/rails-baseball-app'
  end
end
```

```
nodejs -v
-bash: nodejs: command not found
```

こちらでも質問しています
https://teratail.com/questions/305750

Comment: 利用している OS の種類とバージョンを明記してください。`yum` が使えないということであれば代わりに `dnf` を使う必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: OS,バージョンの追記を致しました

Comment: どうやらAWS上で v6.17.1のようでした
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -でnodejsをインストールしました